# Execute() function of CloudTableQuery seems infinite

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

```
Public ReadOnly Property logs() As CloudTableQuery(Of adlog)
Get
Return CreateQuery(Of adlog)("adlog").AsTableServiceQuery()
End Get
End Property
```

I have following code

```
Dim oContext = New kdlib.kdlogs.adlog_context()
Dim q = From adlogs In oContext.logs Where adlogs.PartitionKey = "xxxxxx"
```

Will bring back only 1000 rows

If i add `.Execute()` as i read somewhere:

```
Dim q = From adlogs In oContext.logs.Execute() Where adlogs.PartitionKey = "xxxxxx"
```

Request never ends

I really don't get it.

EDIT based upon successfull answer below

Here it works now

```
Dim azt_context As New tableContextGet
Dim azt_query As CloudTableQuery(Of adlog)
azt_query = azt_context.CreateQuery(Of adlog)("adlog").Where(Function(e) (e.PartitionKey = "xxx")).AsTableServiceQuery()
Dim azt_result = azt_query.Execute()
```

then azt_result.ToList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query will send the query parameter to the storage server, which will send you the filtered results.

Your second query is attempting to pull all the data from the table, and then filter it in memory. That is because `oContext.logs.Execute()` will immediately execute the query, with no parameters. As an aside, it probably will complete though it may take a very long time.

Typically you would want to set up the query first, then call .AsTableServiceQuery(), and then get the results. I don't really know VB.NET, but this should give you the general idea:

```
Public ReadOnly Property logs() As CloudTableQuery(Of adlog)
Get
Return CreateQuery(Of adlog)("adlog")
End Get
End Property

...

Dim oContext = New kdlib.kdlogs.adlog_context() 
Dim q = From adlogs In oContext.logs Where adlogs.PartitionKey = "xxxxxx"
Dim qQuery = q.AsTableServiceContext() //Do this after setting up parameters
Dim qResult = q.ToList()  //Actually executes the query.
```

Comment: The Execute() going before the parameter is key, thank you, pure logic.